# Extract a CSR from PKCS7

Tags: java, security, bouncycastle, pkcs#7, pkcs#10

There is a requirement where I have to extract PKCS10 (CSR) from PKCS7 pem formatted string that I have. Although I can read the contents of the PKCS7, I see that it just a Certificate and not a CSR.

I also ran the pem string with the https://certlogik.com/decoder/ to see what it consists of. All I can see is a valid certificate.
Is there a way where I can get the CSR from the below pem formatted string.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the certificate, you can fill the CSR just getting the information contained in the certificate (subject, public key, ...)
But since you don't have the private key associated to this public key, you won't be able to sign the CSR.